# Making a URL param persistent

Tags: cakephp

This is my custom route.

```
Router::connect(
   "/embed/:ssid/:controller/:action/*",
   array('prefix' => 'embed', 'embed' => true),
   array('ssid')
);
```

How do I make 'ssid' persistent? Every time I use  the Html link helper I don't want to manually specify the ssid param for each link.

I am under the impression I could make it persistent similar to the routing prefixes.

I have already tried this

```
Router::connect(
   "/embed/:ssid/:controller/:action/*",
   array('prefix' => 'embed', 'embed' => true),
   array('ssid', 'ssid' => true)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `persist` key in `Router::connect()` options as explained in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::connect).